# Installing Lilypond in (La)TeX environment

Tags: lilypond

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I have not found the relevant question.

I am trying to use LilyPond in a LaTeX environment.

From ChatGPT I should be able to use a simple file such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lilypond-book}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
\relative{\time 4/4 \tempo 
          c'4 d e f g a b c } 
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

But compiling this, using TeXShop I get an error message:

```
./test.tex:6: LaTeX Error: Environment lilypond undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \begin{lilypond}
                    
?
```

The lilypond-book executable file is in the same directory as my TeX file.

It may be more appropriate to ask this in the TeX SE, but I guess my chances of an answer may be slightly better here.

Comment: You/ChatGPT hasn't set the tempo correctly.  It needs to be something like `\tempo 4=120`

Comment: I see that now, but that is not related to my problem. It seems not to find the lilypond-book file.

Comment: Instead of asking ChatGPT, why not read plain old documentation?

Comment: @JeanAbouSamra Thank You that is a very helpful and constructive comment. I have done that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

`lilypond-book` does not work like that. It is not a TeX module, but a preprocessor that will compile the sources, split and crop the resulting images and create a tex file with these images inserted. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
\relative{
    \time 4/4 \tempo 4=60
    c'4 d e f g a b c
} 
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

compiled using `lilypond-book` gives a tex file like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

{%
\parindent 0pt
\noindent
\ifx\preLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\preLilyPondExample
\fi
\def\lilypondbook{}%
\input{0c/lily-dd5e2542-systems.tex}%
\ifx\postLilyPondExample \undefined
\else
  \expandafter\postLilyPondExample
\fi
}

\end{document}
```

(the included file includes the eps graphics).

If you wish to use a different workflow you can use a different approach (as long as you are using LuaTeX). There is the package `lyluatex` which allows you to do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
\relative{
    \time 4/4 \tempo 4=60
    c'4 d e f g a b c
} 
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

directly in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I am trying your 2nd method and using LuaLaTex, but still get an error ! LaTeX Error: File `lyluatex.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: x

Comment: @Oбжорoв This means you do not have the package installed: https://ctan.org/pkg/lyluatex It is shipped in texlive-music.